# Javascript onClick and onmouseover and onmouseOut

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask how to differentiate between onClick and onMouseOver and onMouseOut.

For instance, 
I use onMouseOver to change the tab background to grey using

```
onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor=Blue;"
```

onMouseOut takes away this background

```
onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor=White;"
```

How do I write a call for onClick that gives a blue background and keeps it there even when the mouse cursor moves away from the tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about you have two CSS classes, "active" and "clicked". They both set the background to blue. On click, you add the "clicked" class. On mouse over, you add the "active" class. On mouse out, you remove the "active" class. If the element had the "clicked" class it'd still have it, and hence keep its color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with event listeners. I recommend using a framework for this, like prototypejs or jquery.

You will need event listeners / observers for observing the mouseOver, mouseOut and click events. When your click event fires, you stop observing for mouseOver and mouseOut. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a check in the MouseOut that only changes the color if it's not already blue.

Comment: well the mouse over color is also blue, so in that case it'd never change the color.

Comment: The OP states that the button should be grey on MouseOver (although the code says blue). OnClick should make the button blue, and when the button is clicked (being blue) MouseOver shouldn't change it. Which means that it should only change if it's not blue.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would add a CSS class to the element which has the active (last clicked on item) state. That CSS class can have priority over the normal styling of the element.

I would even use CSS and not JavaScript for hover state changes.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution is here for your help. Hope it works for you.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function row_mout(mout_value) {
  document.getElementById(mout_value).style.background = "#FFFFFF";
}

function row_mover(mover_value){
  document.getElementById(mover_value).style.background = "#123456";
}

function row_click(click_value) {
 if(document.getElementById('chk_'+click_value).checked == true){
  document.getElementById(click_value).style.background = "#123456";
  document.getElementById(click_value).onmouseout = "";
  document.getElementById(click_value).onmouseover = "";
 }//if over
 else if(document.getElementById('chk_'+click_value).checked == false){
  document.getElementById(click_value).style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  document.getElementById(click_value).onmouseout = function onmouseout(event){
          row_mout(click_value);
        }
  document.getElementById(click_value).onmouseover = function onmouseover(event){
          row_mover(click_value);
        }
 }//else if over
}
```